# Redirect after form POST

Tags: javascript, html, forms, parse-platform, href

I am working on saving information submitted through a form to parse.com and then redirecting to an alternate page once complete. I have the POST working correctly but cannot find the easiest way to redirect to the new page. Here is my code:

```
 <script>
        function validateForm() {
        Parse.initialize("1oFe8znPN2CwcEj14eIYaIOuxGtW35ZpmOazlG3H", "fJhaxIenhcwAdp66T14LKw4OukJ3lG6DLpkq1JVV");
        var TestObject = Parse.Object.extend("iOS");
var testObject = new TestObject();
  testObject.save({Phone: document.forms["appForm"]["phone"].value },{
  success: function(object) {
    $(".success").show();
  },
  error: function(model, error) {
    $(".error").show();
  }
});}
```

and

```
            <input type="text"  name="phone" id="contact_email"  class=" form-control input-email" placeholder="Phone Number">

            <input type="submit" id="sendingbtn" class="btn" value="Submit">
```

I had onclick="location.href='appsuccess.html';" in the submit input but it would push sometimes before the POST. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: changing `window.location` will force a page redirect. `window.location = 'your url here';`

Comment: instead of putting the redirect on onclick, put it inside success.

Answer (score 1):

What about using

```
window.location.href = 'http://redirecturl/';
```

in the success function? ([How to redirect to another webpage in JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-using-jquery))

Answer (score 1):

Since you display a success message on your page, so I would suggest redirecting the user after a delay using setTimeout. The timeout should be initiated after the post returns successfully. So, you should modify your success function to be:

```
function(object) {  
  $(".success").show();  
  window.setTimeout(function() {  
    location.href = "appsuccess.html";  
  }, 1500);  
}
```

This will cause the site to redirect after a 1.5 second delay. You can adjust the timing as needed for the effect you want. Documentation on setTimeout: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout